# How to set up gcc and g++ on a Windows environment properly?

Tags: c++, windows, gcc, mingw

I am new to C++. I want to have a compiler for C++ on my Windows10 system. Since I plan to write my sources directly with notepad++, I'd like to be able to compile it in command line.

As people suggested, I installed `MinGW-get`, and from there installed `gcc` packages.

My `MinGW` is installed directly in `C:\`, as suggested, and under `C:\MinGW\bin`. There I can find `c++.exe`, `g++.exe`, `gcc.exe`...

I have already added `C:\MinGW\bin` to the `PATH` system environment.

However, when I try to compile codes from command line, it reminds me that

> 'g++' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file."

How do I fix my environment to compile things?

Comment: You can actually install linux stuff in windows these days. Might also help the OP since it should work well with GCC: https://www.howtogeek.com/249966/how-to-install-and-use-the-linux-bash-shell-on-windows-10/

Comment: Check your PATH if the location has been added there via the installer. If not, you'll need to add it. In some cases you might need to restart Windows, or at least open a new cmd terminal (the environment is not auto-updated in cmd terminals which were  already open).

Comment: Start the MinGW bash shell as command line.

Comment: `MinGW` and `g++` being _"software tools commonly used by programmer"_ I'd say this question is actually on-topic (source: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)). It could be improved though.

Comment: Altering the `PATH` environment variable require to logoff/logon before having effect. As always with Windows: reboot your computer and try again.

Comment: What does the PATH command say your path is?

Comment: @Lumi Wang can you show PATH setting? Looks like the path is not set correctly.

Comment: Have you considered using a Linux VM or Docker ?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch thanks. I have the complete path set, appropriately I believe, cuz I had some experience with it earlier. That's why I am asking the question. You are absolutely right that Linux is more developer friendly. The same setting up on Linux took only 30s... I just wonder why it doesn't work on my Windows.

Comment: @axalis thanks for the reply. I kill the command window and reopen everytime I update the PATH. I have also tried reboot Windows, but nothing helped. If you could elaborate on what do you mean by "Location added via the installer"?

Comment: Stupid question, did you put the .exe after the g++?

Comment: Many thanks to everybody. I fixed the problem, inspired by @MartinBonner 's answer, and checked the path command.. Then it occurred to me that I set the cpp compiler as a "system environment" instead of "Path in system environment". 
This is indeed a very stupid question, and BasileStarynkevitch did point out the source of this problem at first.
Many thanks again.